# How can I bold a EditorGUILayout.Toggle in EditorWindow script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Before I asked about how to bold a GUI.Toggle
The answer was to create a style:

```
GUIStyle myToggleStyle = new GUIStyle(GUI.skin.toggle);
```

Then set it to bold:

```
myToggleStyle.fontStyle = FontStyle.Bold;
```

And last use it with the Toggle:

```
GUI.Toggle(new Rect(5, 10, 200, 60), false, "Select All", myToggleStyle);
```

But now I'm using another Toggle with the same text "Select All" but this time it's EditorGILayout.Toggle and I don't need or want to use GUI.Toggle since GUI.Toggle need a Rect.

The problem is that with EditorGUILayout.Toggle the myToggleStyle is not working. It does nothing and not making the text/font to be bold.

This is inside the OnGUI:

```
EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();
selectAll[i] = EditorGUILayout.Toggle("Select All", selectAll[i]);
if (EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck())
              SelectDeselectAll(i);
```

I tried this:

```
EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();
GUIStyle myToggleStyle = new GUIStyle(GUI.skin.toggle);
myToggleStyle.fontStyle = FontStyle.Bold;
selectAll[i] = EditorGUILayout.Toggle("Select All", selectAll[i], myToggleStyle);
if (EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck())
    SelectDeselectAll(i);
```

But it's not making the "Select All" bold.

Answer (score 1):

A working Solution:

```
EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();
var origFontStyle = EditorStyles.label.fontStyle;
EditorStyles.label.fontStyle = FontStyle.Bold;
selectAll[i] = EditorGUILayout.Toggle("Select All", selectAll[i]);
EditorStyles.label.fontStyle = origFontStyle;
if (EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck())
    SelectDeselectAll(i);
```

Comment: the `EditorStyles.toggle` is unnecessary